# regex has no method test

Tags: javascript, regex

ATM machines allow *4 or 6 digit* PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but **exactly** *4 digits or exactly 6 digits*.

If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return `true`, else return `false`.

E.g.:

```
validatePIN("1234") === true
validatePIN("12345") === false
validatePIN("a234") === false
```

Why my code doesn't work?

```
var r = new RegExp('^\\d+$');
function validatePIN (pin) {
  if(pin.test(r) && pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `r.test(pin)`. `test` is a method on RegExp, not String. Docs would point this out. But why not do `/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/`?

Comment: Why not use the regular expression `'^\\d{4}(\\{2})?$'` and get rid of the length test?

Comment: r.test(pin) or pin.match(r)

Comment: yes test is method of regular expression not a string.so try r.test(pin)

Answer (score 3):

You may do all in a single regex..

```
var r = new RegExp('^(\\d{4}|\\d{6})$');
```

So the condition would be,

```
function validatePIN (pin) {
 return r.test(pin);
}
```

Comment: or perhaps `return r.test(pin);`

Answer (score 2):

```
x && y || z
```

Is interpreted as:

```
(x && y) || z
```

It will return `true` if the length is *6* even if it's **not** *only digits*. To fix this, you can add brackets:

```
x && (y || z)
```

Comment: This is a problem, but a bit secondary. First it will result in a run-time error, since there is no `test` method on String.

Comment: @torazaburo, Darin already pointed that out. Trying to be constructive with another answer.

Comment: `x && y || z
Becomes

(x && y) || z` ?

Comment: @guest271314, `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: @ndn _"It will return true if the length is 6 even if it's not only digits."_  Yes. This is portion of description at Answer that did not initially follow, here. If `(x && y)` is `true` , will not reach `z` ,  correct ?

Comment: @guest271314, here `x` = *is only digits*, `y` = *has length 4*, `z` = *has length 6*. You want `x & y` or `x & z` to be true. The way it is written, `z` alone is enough.

Comment: @ndn Should parenthesis to follow logic be `x && (y || z)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method on the regex instance, not on the string input:

```
if (r.test(pin) && (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6)) {
```

Also notice the precedence of the logical operators.

Comment: You failed to correct the parens, must be `r.test(pin) && (pin.length===4 || pin.length===6)`.

Comment: That's true, I will update.