# Regex in javascript global catch failed

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var r = new RegExp('^[0-9]*$');
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  if(r.test(pin) && pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(validatePin(3627i1));
```

What's wrong with my regex above? I expect `true` in this case.

Comment: first and foremost `validatePin(3627i1)` that is not the function you have defined

Comment: [ndn's answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34690882/3832970) already answers this question. Just place the logical parentheses where they must be. `r.test(pin) && (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6)` will let any characters in the input, but will restrict it to 4 or 6 occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing much is wrong but these conditions will not evaluate correctly:

```
r.test(pin) && pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6
```

As it effectively means `(r.test(pin) && pin.length == 4) || pin.length == 6` due to `&&` at higher operator precedence than `||`.

You need to enclose conditions in parentheses:

```
r.test(pin) && (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6)
```

btw you don't even need to check for length afterwards as you can do that in regex itself:

```
var r = /^[0-9]{4}(?:[0-9]{2})?$/
```

Now this regex will match either 4 digit number or a six digit number.

Comment: woah why should I wrap the length condition? I don't get it

Comment: As I explained in my answer that it is effectively being evaluated as `(r.test(pin) && pin.length == 4) || pin.length == 6` but what you actually want is this: `r.test(pin) && (pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6)`

Answer (score 0):

`validatePin` is not the same as `validatePIN` and `3627i1` is not the same as `'3627i1'`.

So make sure that you are calling the correct function and passing it a correct argument:

```
console.log(validatePIN('3627i1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax errors in your code,

```
var r = new RegExp('^[0-9]*$');
function validatePIN (pin) {
  //return true or false
  if(r.test(pin) && pin.length == 4 || pin.length == 6){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(validatePIN("3627i1")); //call valid function, parameter = string
```